# How to debug tomcat LDAP realm queries

Tags: debugging, tomcat, ldap

I have a tomcat realm setup which is working great to authenticate users but it doesn't seem to be pulling Group membership correctly.  Is there some way to go about adding debug info to some log?

I'm assuming i probably need to add some log-4-j config somewhere but I'm unsure where to look.

All the documentation says is:

> Debugging and exception messages logged by a Realm will be recorded by
>   the logging configuration associated with the container for the realm:
>   its surrounding Context, Host, or Engine.

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to look at the source code. It will have a log level somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [here](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2010/03/enable-debugtrace-level-logging-for.html):

> Solution:
>   You have to edit the $CATALINA_HOME/conf/logging.properties file.
>
> 1. Configure debug logging for Realms and Authentication
>      Insert the following lines (in blue):

```
############################################################
# Facility specific properties.
# Provides extra control for each logger.
############################################################
# This would turn on trace-level for everything
# the possible levels are: SEVERE, WARNING, INFO, CONFIG, FINE, FINER, FINEST or ALL
#org.apache.catalina.level = ALL
#org.apache.catalina.handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
org.apache.catalina.realm.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.realm.useParentHandlers = true
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.level = ALL
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.useParentHandlers = true

org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].level = INFO
org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].handlers = 2localhost.org.apache.juli.FileHandler
```

> This will give you debug/trace level logging to console and the file assuming you've kept the default config. But you only see debug in the console, not the catalina.[date yyyy-MM-dd].log file - in fact, the log file empty? The buffering means the file-logging is only written when the buffer is full.